# Android. Save and reestablish value of chronometer (reversing screen)

Tags: android, chronometer

My question is rather simple, but i can't handle with him.
I have chronometer field in  my design.

I want to save them for avoid lost value of time by revert the screen (recreate new activity)

I use for save

```
    public Object onRetainConfigurationInstance(){
    return timeSeconds;
}
```

And for reestablish `timeSeconds = (Chronometer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();`

But it doesn't work. Could somebody help me? What parameter i must save for reestablish chronometer time?

Comment: `But it doesn't work.`  This tells us nothing.  *Exactly* what happens?  How do you know that timeSeconds is not the correct value?

Comment: Simply it begins to count by beginning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putLong(TIME_KEY, timeSeconds.getBase());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    if((savedInstanceState !=null)
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(TIME_KEY)){
        timeSeconds.setBase(savedInstanceState.getLong(TIME_KEY));
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `onSaveInstanceState()` to save data between orientation changes, your code can look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putLong("time_seconds", timeSeconds);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Then you can get stored value inside the `onCreate()`, which is called as the `Activity` gets recreated when orientation changes:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    long timeSeconds = savedInstanceState.getLong("time_seconds");
    // other code from onCreate()
}
```

Comment: Egor, thanks for help. It works with some modifications. Maybe it'll be useful for some beginners.